# pd.to_datetime from int64 is giving 1970s for dates

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, datetime

I am reading ohlc from sqlite3, and my index is of type int64:

```
                           index   open   high    low  close   volume  trade_count       vwap ticker
30273  2022-09-23 10:11:00+00:00  22.48  22.63  22.40  22.41  12289.0         13.0  22.417248    BKR
```

When I print the df.index I get:

```
        ...
        23127, 23128, 23129, 23130, 23131, 23132, 23133, 23134, 23135,
        23136],
       dtype='int64', length=2427)
```

I then convert the index to a datetime:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from ohlc_minutes", conn)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit='s')
```

Which gives me:

```
           ...
           '1970-01-03 16:15:48', '1970-01-03 16:15:49',
           '1970-01-03 16:15:50', '1970-01-03 16:15:51',
           '1970-01-03 16:15:52', '1970-01-03 16:15:53',
           '1970-01-03 16:15:54', '1970-01-03 16:15:55',
           '1970-01-03 16:15:56', '1970-01-03 16:15:57'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=2629, freq=None)
```

Which converts my date to 1970.

I just want it to convert to a normal datetime, using all the information that appears in the index of my df, e.g:

```
2022-09-23 10:11:00+00:00
```

UPDATE

Tried using `.loc` as suggested by jkr:

```
df.loc['index'] =  pd.to_datetime(df.loc['index'], unit='s')
```

Which gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dan/Documents/code/wolfhound/vectorbt.py", line 19, in <module>
    df.loc['index'] =  pd.to_datetime(df.loc['index'], unit='s')
  File "/home/dan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 967, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "/home/dan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1205, in _getitem_axis
    return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
  File "/home/dan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1153, in _get_label
    return self.obj.xs(label, axis=axis)
  File "/home/dan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3864, in xs
    loc = index.get_loc(key)
  File "/home/dan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py", line 389, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'index'
```

Comment: I think it’s because you’re accessing df.index. Try with df.loc[“index”] to get the column named index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is `index` is column, so first convert it to `df.index`, also omit `unit='s'`:

```
#index column to df.index
df = df.set_index('index')
#convert to DatetimeIndex
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Or:

```
#convert index column to datetimes
df['index'] = pd.to_datetime(df['index'])
#convert column index to df.index
df = df.set_index('index')
```

Answer (score 1):

`to_datetime` usses per default POSIX time (see [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) `If 'unix' (or POSIX) time; origin is set to 1970-01-01.`)

You can change either specify the `origin` or give an `offset` if you have POSIX time but without year (relative)

What format has your input?

Comment: i guess the problem is solved now when you correct set the index to column named `index` instead of the primery key?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the int is the number of seconds since epoch. See for example https://www.epochconverter.com/